# python json returns list of...( double linked dicts) ? how to search key get value?

Tags: python, json

I have a json structure that looks like this:

```
 hrl=
 { "hourly": [
 {
 "FCT":{
       "time":"",
       "cvl": "6am"
       },
  "wind":"brzy",
  "tmp":{
        "brm":"hot",
        "cel":"37"
       },
  "FCT":{
        "time":"",
        "cvl":"7am"
        }
   }
        .... list continues ..
  ]
  }
```

Desired output is list of the hours(cvl) and the tmp

Ive tried a variety of list-comprhensions, along the lines of: 
    `CVL = [ v for k,v in parsed_json["FCT"].iteritems() if k==["cvl"] ]`

I cant seem to get past type errors: such as index must be int not string, or I just filter out everything and get an empty array.

what is going on?

(thanks in advance)

Comment: the key FCT exists two times in the same dictionary

Answer (score 2):

```
hrl = { 
    "hourly": [
        {
            "FCT": {"time":"", "cvl": "6am"},
            "wind": "brzy",
            "tmp": {"brm":"hot", "cel":"37"},
            "FCT": {"time": "", "cvl":"7am"}
        }
        #.... list continues ..
    ]
}

print hrl["hourly"][0]["FCT"]["cvl"]
print hrl["hourly"][0]["tmp"]["cel"]

--output:--
7am
37
```

On second thought, it looks like you didn't post a very good representation of your data structure.  It makes more sense if it looks like this:

```
hrl = { 
    "hourly": [
        {
            "FCT": {"time":"", "cvl": "6am"},
            "wind": "brzy",
            "tmp": {"brm":"hot", "cel":"37"},
        },

        {
            "FCT": {"time":"", "cvl": "7am"},
            "wind": "windy",
            "tmp": {"brm":"cool", "cel":"20"},
        }
    ]
}

print hrl["hourly"][0]["FCT"]["cvl"]
print hrl["hourly"][0]["tmp"]["cel"]

print hrl["hourly"][1]["FCT"]["cvl"]
print hrl["hourly"][1]["tmp"]["cel"]

--output:--
6am
37
7am
20

results = [
    (_dict["FCT"]["cvl"], _dict["tmp"]["cel"])
    for _dict in hrl["hourly"]
]

print results

--output:--
[('6am', '37'), ('7am', '20')]
```

hrl["hourly"] is an array of dictionaries.  In python, you can iterate over an array without using indexes by employing a for-in loop:

```
for color in ["red", "green", "blue"]:
    print color

--output:--
red
green 
blue
```

So you just need to grab the array, hrl["hourly"], and use a for-in loop to select each dictionary in the array--no integer indexes required.

One tip: the only part of the data structure you are interested in is the array, so you shouldn't even be saying your data structure is a dict.   Just write:

```
arr = hrl["hourly"]
```

Now you are dealing with an array, so you don't have to worry about some of the nesting.  Taking that further, you can write:

```
outer_dict = arr[0]
inner_dict_hour = outer_dict["FCT"]
inner_dict_tmp = outer_dict["tmp"]
```

Now you have two non-nested dictionaries.  Getting the temperature, for instance, is easy:

```
 tmp = inner_dict_tmp["cel"]
```

From there, you can substitute what inner_dict_tmp is equal to:

```
 tmp = inner_dict_tmp      ["cel"]
             |
             v
 tmp = outer_dict["tmp"]   ["cel"]
```

And substituting for outer_dict:

```
 tmp = outer_dict  ["tmp"]["cel"]
           |
           v
 tmp =   arr[0]    ["tmp"]["cel"]
```

Then substituting for arr:

```
 tmp =     arr         [0]["tmp"]["cel"]
            |
            v
 tmp = hrl["hourly']   [0]["tmp"]["cel"]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the exercise in seeing how the data-obj unwinds. The code for list comprehension helped immensely!  Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
CVL = [ v for k,v in parsed_json['hourly'][0]["FCT"].iteritems() if k==["cvl"] ]
```

instead.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the reply (;this does not work for arrays).  Look at the unwinding example, as well as the above use of _dict in the list_cmprhns; (helps get your head around [list/tuple/array] VS {dicts} and down the right track... -best